# Java Applet says Java is out of date

Tags: java-applet

When I go to this page to verify my java version, it says my java is out of date. It gives me a link, I update my java through that link. But I still get the same message when I try  again. http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaVersionTests/JavaTests.html

If I then click on the details after it fails to load, it says I am using JRE 1.7. However if I go to the java control panel, it clearly says JRE 1.8 is enabled. I am not sure what is wrong ?

Details:

Java Plug-in 10.55.2.14 Using JRE version 1.7.0_55-b14 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM User home directory = C:\Users\Laurence

================

I am using firefox on windows 8. I had the same problem with IE, safari seems unavailable for win 8

Comment: Why are you not using oracles website to verify the version installed. I promise you safari works on windows 8.  The linked website can't even verify your running java 8

Answer (score 0):

The website you posted doesn't work for me either (and I have a working Java plug-in).  My preferred site for testing Java is [this one](http://javatester.org/version.html).  What are you results there?